# Increase clickable URL length in Fiddler Inspector

Tags: url, fiddler

Fiddler generates a clickable URL for the link after the text "GET" in raw view, but it silently truncates the linked portion after around 2^9 characters.
I didn't know about this silent truncation and spent some time trying to figure out why a JavaScript library wasn't generating proper URLs when in fact it was.

How do I increase the clickable URL length?

For example, the link in the first line of:

```
GET http://localhost:62865/API/Crud?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=ID&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=NAME&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=FAVORITENUM&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=DOB&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1417319047626 HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost:62865/Home/Index
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost:62865
Pragma: no-cache
```

...Is silently truncated to:

```
http://localhost:62865/API/Crud?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=ID&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=NAME&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=FAVORITENUM&columns%5B2%5D%5Bn
```

An obvious workaround is to highlight the entire link, copy it to the clipboard, and paste it into a browser's URL bar but figuring out that the link is bad in the first place is non-obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Most Windows components assume URLs will not exceed [2083 characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/08/13/url-length-limits-in-internet-explorer.aspx) in length; the [`EM_AUTOURLDETECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787991(v=vs.85).aspx) behavior for the RichEdit version used by .NET apparently has a lower limit.

For the next release of Fiddler (2.4.9.8 and later) I will use a trick to get Fiddler to force .NET to use a later version of the RichEdit control; it assumes a longer URL limit.

FWIW: If you're really trying to grab the request URL, the simplest way is to hit `CTRL+U` on the selected Session in the Web Sessions list.